# How do i use asset image in flutter for setting wallpaper in android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am unable to find the solution of setting asset image as wallpaper in android, while i am doing everything right as documented in official flutter document ion, in below image Set As Wallpaper button uses Method channel and use native code in java activity but could not set this image as wallpaper from java activity. Please guide.
This image loaded from local assets folder in flutter

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/wallpaper_manager 
You can set wallpaper in Home screen or Lock screen 
wall paper can from a `File` or `Asset`

code snippet

```
Future<void> setWallpaperFromAsset() async {
    setState(() {
      _wallpaperAsset = "Loading";
    });
    String result;
    String assetPath = "assets/tmp1.jpg";
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromAsset(
          assetPath, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    } on PlatformException {
      result = 'Failed to get wallpaper.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _wallpaperAsset = result;
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_manager/wallpaper_manager.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  String _wallpaperFile = 'Unknown';
  String _wallpaperAsset = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await WallpaperManager.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> setWallpaperFromFile() async {
    setState(() {
      _wallpaperFile = "Loading";
    });
    String result;
    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542435503-956c469947f6');
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
          file.path, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    } on PlatformException {
      result = 'Failed to get wallpaper.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _wallpaperFile = result;
    });
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> setWallpaperFromAsset() async {
    setState(() {
      _wallpaperAsset = "Loading";
    });
    String result;
    String assetPath = "assets/tmp1.jpg";
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromAsset(
          assetPath, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    } on PlatformException {
      result = 'Failed to get wallpaper.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _wallpaperAsset = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Platform Version"),
                onPressed: initPlatformState,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Set wallpaper from file"),
                onPressed: setWallpaperFromFile,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text('Wallpaper status: $_wallpaperFile\n'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Set wallpaper from asset"),
                onPressed: setWallpaperFromAsset,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text('Wallpaper status: $_wallpaperAsset\n'),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you chunhunghan , your answer is very helpful in my said issue, just one thing from your code, i am getting error in setWallpaperFromAsset() async and could not load asset image, while working perfect for network image.